# Using R function in C#

Tags: c#, r

I have a function that is written in the R programming language and I want to use it in a c# application. I need an API that will work as an R interface in my c# program, and don't need R installed to work, because the c# program will be used in machines that will not have R installed on them.

Comment: I have a function in R that i need to call giving it an input, it will return some output, what should i use?

Comment: You should use R.

Comment: it's a very difficult function that i can't rewrite in c# so i need another way to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to install [R.Net library](https://rdotnet.codeplex.com/) to run R in .NET Framework.

Comment: thank you Maxim Goncharuk, if i use R.Net, will my application run even machines that don't have R installed in them ?

Comment: @NadjibBendaoud you would need to have native R DLL on you machine. If it is only one function, it would be better to rewrite it in C# without any dependencies to R.

Comment: yes i know but it's a very compliated function that uses dataframes and operations on dataframes, so it will be difficult to use rewrite it in c#